# How to order Hibernate search results on complex type

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I want to fuzzy search all vehicles based on the licensePlate and order after the fleetCustomer.customerId.

So far I could do the fuzzy search but the ordering part it seems that is to difficult to do it on my own in the time I have.

The version of hibernate-search library is 5.5.5.final

I have 2 entities:

vehicle:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE")
@Indexed
public class VehicleDao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "vehicle_id")
    private Long vehicleId;

    @Column(name = "license_plate", length = 50)
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    private String licensePlate;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fleetCustomer")
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    private CustomerDao fleetCustomer;

    ...
}
```

and customer:

```
@Embeddable
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
public class CustomerDao {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long customerId;

...

}
```

What I tried so far is to add the ordering attribute as a field to the search but this does not work, no results are returned.

This is what I have tried so far, the fuzzy search is working.
From the code you can seed that the vehicle which has the fleetCustomer.customerId = 1025 is required to be the first.

```
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = b.bool()
                .must( b.keyword().fuzzy().onField("licensePlate").boostedTo(3)
                        .matching("mhp 070").createQuery() )
//        .must( b.keyword().onField("fleetCustomer.customerId").ignoreFieldBridge()
//                .matching("1025").createQuery() )
                .createQuery();

        final org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery fullTextQuery =
                fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery , VehicleDao.class);

        fullTextQuery.setFirstResult(1);
        fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(5);

        List<T> resultList = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I know this post is getting old, but if this comment can help fellows. The `should` keyword is what you should have used. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612771/4629012).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order your results, you shouldn't change the query. You should add a sort.

**EDIT:** I didn't see you were using Search 5.5. Here is a solution for Search 5.5. This version is getting old, by the way, you should consider upgrading if you can.

Add a field to sort on on the customer ID:

```
@Embeddable
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
public class CustomerDao {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false)
    @Field(name = "customerId_sort") // <== Add this
    @SortableField(forField = "customerId_sort")  // <== And this
    private Long customerId;

...

}
```

And then add a sort when querying:

```
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = b.bool()
                .must( b.keyword().fuzzy().onField("licensePlate").boostedTo(3)
                        .matching("mhp 070").createQuery() )
                .createQuery();

        final org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery fullTextQuery =
                fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery , VehicleDao.class);


        // Add this
        org.apache.lucene.search.Sort sort = new org.apache.lucene.search.Sort( new org.apache.lucene.search.SortField( "fleetCustomer.customerId_sort", org.apache.lucene.search.SortField.Type.LONG ) )
        fullTextQuery.setSort( sort );

        fullTextQuery.setFirstResult(1);
        fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(5);

        List<T> resultList = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

If you are new to Hibernate Search, and especially if you are also new to the full-text world, I would recommend having a look at [the section about sorts in the Hibernate Search documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#_sorting).

---

Original solution (for Search 5.6 and above):

Add a field to sort on on the customer ID:

```
@Embeddable
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
public class CustomerDao {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false)
    @Field(name = "customerId_sort") // <== Add this
    @SortableField(forField = "customerId_sort")  // <== And this
    private Long customerId;

...

}
```

And then add a sort when querying:

```
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = b.bool()
                .must( b.keyword().fuzzy().onField("licensePlate").boostedTo(3)
                        .matching("mhp 070").createQuery() )
                .createQuery();

        final org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery fullTextQuery =
                fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery , VehicleDao.class);


        // Add this
        org.apache.lucene.search.Sort sort = b.sort().byField( "fleetCustomer.customerId_sort" ).createSort();
        fullTextQuery.setSort(sort);

        fullTextQuery.setFirstResult(1);
        fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(5);

        List<T> resultList = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

If you are new to Hibernate Search, and especially if you are also new to the full-text world, I would recommend having a look at [the section about sorts in the Hibernate Search documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-sorting).

Comment: I do not want a sort the results necessarely,  I just want the records that have the required customerId to be the first. This is not the same thing as sorting...

Comment: thanks for helping and for that you have my appreciation, but I do not see how you provide the expected customerId value to the query...

Comment: Ok, that's not what I understood. Why exactly do you want a specific item to be at the top? Is it some element that the user selects? Or is it a "special value"? If so, is there any way to recognize that special value other than using its ID?